# Show tab control inside wpf combobox drop down

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid, tabcontrol

I want to show a `TabControl` with each tab having `DataGrid` inside the `ComboBox` drop down. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - Yes

You can use template for doing this, create a `template` for `ComboBox` having `Datagrid`. Or you can modify the `ControlTemplate` of `ComboBox`, as done in this article -

[WPF DataGrid as ComboBox Dropdown](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/xaml/e8585e81-34c8-4808-ae3e-b8b35d738842/wpf-datagrid-as-combobox-dropdown.aspx)

But how useful that would be I am doubtful.